# Text search within single article content

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, module, articles

I have inserted the Joomla search module in an article.

Now I wish that this module would allow me to search only in the article in which it is present and not throughout the site!

Is it possible?

Comment: What sort of results are you expecting the search module to show when used if it's only for 1 article?

Comment: I have to search only within a site Faqs! ok?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Joomla search module will not work to search within a single article. But there are several ways you can make your FAQ more user friendly, depending on how complex it is. Here's a couple of ideas:

1. Tell the users to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or simply <kbd>F3</kbd>) to open the in-page search box to search on the current page. This works on all browsers (as far as I know).
2. Implement a in-page search box using JavaScript. I found [the following code](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm) that should work, although it's quite old (the site talks about Netscape, a browser from the era of the dinosaurs...):

   ```
   var TRange=null;

   function findString (str) {
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
    var strFound;
    if (window.find) {

     // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

     strFound=self.find(str);
     if (!strFound) {
      strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
      while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
     }
   }
    else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

     // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

     if (TRange!=null) {
      TRange.collapse(false);
      strFound=TRange.findText(str);
      if (strFound) TRange.select();
     }
     if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
      TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
      strFound=TRange.findText(str);
      if (strFound) TRange.select();
   }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
     alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
     return;
    }
    if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
    return;
   }
   ```
3. Use a [knowledgebase extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/faq/jd-knowledgebase) that has built-in search function.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Joomla "Search module" search through content areas in CMS database. It does not search in a published article, on the browser side.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of Joomla modules which allow you to search for text within the same page using JavaScript.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for https://jdev.l-it.co.za/products/in-page-search-term-highlighter

This module basically lets you search for content within the same page you are on, similar to the CTRL+F browser search feature.